# Sliding pages inside an activity through touch swiping

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-animation

I want to have an activity in which the user can navigate from left to right and vice versa to move through fragments.
This navigation desired to occur through a horizontal touch swiping.

What is the best way?

[image]

Comment: have come across view pager stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager` to do this. you may want to view [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this example have some troubles. Do you examine it yourself? It is crashed when I click on `Screen Slide` item.

Answer (score 0):

According to me implementing #viewFlipper class will be better.